# Php to .xlsm (Macro enabled files)

Tags: php, macros, phpexcel

I am trying to use PhpExcel library to export data to an .xlsm file.I know the macro enabled files are not officially supported.
Does anyone know how to do it?Or an other way around?

Comment: Not much actually.I have only seen a few post about doing this with openpyxl.But i would prefer to stay on php if it is possible.I currently use an other macro to copy from the exported xls to the xlsm.

Answer (score 0):

PhpExcel doesn't support macro reading and writing